# Allow HTML input tag and values on wysihtml5

Tags: wysihtml5

I'm using wysihtml5 with bootstrap-wysihtml5 to save html templates (and at some point I need to load them on wysihtml5). I want to be able to allow the input tag on the editor.

The user workflow should be this:

1. Create a template with a "input=text" and a "input=checkbox" and save it.
2. Load the saved template on wysiwyg5 (it will show the inputs so the user can check the checkbox, input some value on the other, add some another HTML, etc)
3. Save all data again (including the input values/checked status)

In the Bootstrap-wysihtml5 parserRules I added:

```
"input": { check_attributes: { "type": "alt", "name":"alt","id":"alt", "value": "alt" }},
```

And this works fine to add (on HTML source view) <input/> elements but I cannot save the value the user insert on the inputs.

Any hints on how to accomplish this?

**Edit 1:**

Here is a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/KuA9Z/1/

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
$('#id-of-textarea').val()
```

This returns:

```
<input type="text"> Some text.
```

If this does not work, can you provide a fiddle with your code?

I am using my own fork https://github.com/Waxolunist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower/ with bootstrap3.

Comment: Thx for the fiddle. I tried it and I think that with the current editor this is not accomplishable (the checked thing). A solution would be to make a fork and do some additions to the parser rules to allow attributes without a value. But I would separate template creation from data input anyways. For the input value the solution would be to add a script on the input to sync the input value with the value in the html executed before val() (look with firebug on an input field, the source is unchanged).

Comment: I was able to evolve this a little and get the values (with a acceptable workaround for the checkbox): http://jsfiddle.net/KuA9Z/4/. Now I have a problem with pressing spacebar inside the input:text but I think maybe wysihtml5 is not exactly a good component to do this kind of thing... will play around a little more and maybe search for another solution. Thanks for your help.